# My ubuntu shutdowns unexpectedly many times Please help

Tags: 20.04, shutdown

[Logs page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dsqK.png)

[Logs page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOEq6.png)

[Logs page 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZslP.png)

I am having a 8gb DDR4 Ram
and an i7 8th gen processor
and an 1TB hard drive.
My pc is shutdowned unexpectedly before 1 week when using shotwell to edit videos, and i thought the problem is with shotwell,
but that's not the case. Even if i am browsing in google, my pc shutdowns and one time i just entered my password and logged in and boom,
my system shutdowned.

Comment: While supplying a large number of pictures of your log file can help narrow down a problem, could you edit your question to include some specifics? Perhaps *when* the machine shuts down? The type of hardware? What software might be the issue? Without this, it seems as though you are holding us accountable for solving your problem.

Comment: I am having a 8gb DDR4 Ram and an i7 8th gen processor and an 1TB hard drive. My pc is shutdowned unexpectedly before 1 week when using shotwell to edit videos, and i thought the problem is with shotwell, but that's not the case. Even if i am browsing in google my pc shutdowns and one time i just entered my password and logged in and boom, my system shutdowned.

Comment: This confuses me greatly. From the screenshots that you posted, I see that you probably write software. Writing software requires an incredible amount of specificity, with people (ideally) understanding the stack they're coding for. When people report a bug like "It doesn't work", is there no follow-up to get more details? So, let's see ... this is a notebook of some kind, the battery is darn near zero, and the `boltd` messages are clear. I'm going to go out on a limb and say that your battery is dying. Plug your computer in and see if it shuts down.

Comment: it had happened to me before even the battery is full i think power is not the problem.

Comment: And whenever i power on my pc the log shows this kind of message: shutdown scheduled (t - 20.0 seconds). and i didn't scheduled a shutdown